# More than one target with the same function

Tags: javascript, video

I trying to use Video JS HD Toggle Plugin to delivery more features to my users but I do know how to have two videos at same page and use the HD plugin on my player. How can I change the code and put it to work with multiple videos?

```js
        
        function HDtoggle () {
           
     var HD1 = false;
     /* It is the variable which tells us that that HD video is getting played or not.
     HD1 = false ---> video is not HD
     HD1 = true ----> video is HD */
          
             videojs.HD = videojs.Button.extend({
           /* @constructor */
               init: function(player, options){
                 videojs.Button.call(this, player, options);
                 this.on('click', this.onClick);
               }
             });
            
   /* Changing sources by clicking on HD button */
   /* This function is called when HD button is clicked */
            videojs.HD.prototype.onClick = function() {
          
          
         var HDsrc = $("#video_1").find( "video" ).attr("HD"); 
   /* Value of HD attribute in video tag is saved in HDsrc. */
         var noHDsrc = $("#video_1").find( "video" ).attr("nonHD");
   /* Value of nonHD attribute in video tag is saved in noHDsrc. */
          
   if (HD1) { /* If video is not HD */
         var css = document.createElement("style");
         css.type = "text/css";
         css.innerHTML = ".vjs-control.vjs-HD-button { color: silver; font-weight:normal; text-shadow: 0 0 5em #fff;}";
    /* Changing the HD button to initial styling when we play non HD video by clicking on HD button.*/
         document.body.appendChild(css);
         videojs("video_1").src([{type: "video/mp4", src: noHDsrc }]);
   
         videojs("video_1").play();
   /* This automatically plays the video when we click on HD button to change the source.*/
         HD1 = false;
         }
         else { /* if video is HD */
         var css = document.createElement("style");
         css.type = "text/css";
         css.innerHTML = ".vjs-control.vjs-HD-button { color: #36D8DE; font-weight:bold; text-shadow: 0 0 1em #fff;}";
  /*This css applies when HD video is played. You can easily change the blue color of HD button by changing the value of color above. If you would like to remove the shadow from HD button, remove text-shadow from above.*/
  document.body.appendChild(css);
         videojs("video_1").src([{type: "video/mp4", src: HDsrc }]);
         videojs("video_1").play();
          /*This automatically plays the video when we  click on HD button to change the source.*/
   HD1 = true;
         }
          
         };
         
   /* Create HD button */
   var createHDButton = function() {
               var props = {
                   className: 'vjs-HD-button vjs-control',
                   innerHTML: '<div class="vjs-control-content">' + ('HD') + '</div>',
                   role: 'button',
                   'aria-live': 'polite', 
                   tabIndex: 0
                 };
               
               return videojs.Component.prototype.createEl(null, props);
             };
         
   /* Add HD button to the control bar */
         var HD;
             videojs.plugin('HD', function() {
               var options = { 'el' : createHDButton() };
               HD = new videojs.HD(this, options);
               this.controlBar.el().appendChild(HD.el());
             });
         
          /* Set Up Video.js Player */
   var vid = videojs("video_1", {
              plugins : { HD : {} }
            });
             
}
    HDtoggle();
```

```css
 .vjs-default-skin .vjs-control.vjs-HD-button {
         display: block;
   font-size: 1.5em;
         line-height: 2;
         position: relative;
         top: 0;
         float:right;
   left: 10px;
         height: 100%;
         text-align: center;
         cursor: pointer;
         }
```

```html
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.6.4/video.js"></script>
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.6.4/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


 <video id="video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" HD="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" nonHD="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" width="640" height="480" controls>
         <source type="video/mp4" src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4">
      </video>

 <video id="video_2" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" HD="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" nonHD="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" width="640" height="480" controls>
         <source type="video/mp4" src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4">
      </video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just looking to make your code work among as many videos as available then that is pretty simple and is accomplished via loops. You just have to grab the videos in your page and loop through them. I first selected the videos by class name with jquery, in this case `$(.video-js)`, looped through them with jquery's `.each` (https://api.jquery.com/each/), and then called the `HDtoggle()` function for each one and passed in the unique video id as a parameter called `videoID`. Then just replaced your instances of `video_1` with that parameter. Here is a fiddle with it working for both videos:

http://jsfiddle.net/parnj1Lj/2/

Creating loops is one of the most important parts of programming. This will now work for as many videos that you add as long as they have the video-js class and a unique id.

Comment: Your code works to add the button, but when i try to click on it the code doesn't bring the video and crash.

Answer (score 0):

> Creating loops is one of the most important parts of programming

true, but creating a plugin for a general use and not for one hard coded example is even better :)